# jsdom svg transform transitions - Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined

Tags: node.js, d3.js, svg, transition, jsdom

I am trying to use [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/) in node.js to render millions of rows.

I render the charts, and then return the svg. However it only works when is disable transitions using `dc.disableTransitions = true;`

I want to use transitions because it conveys information, and looks nicer. However I get the following error

`http://localhost/d3/d3.js:5943
var t = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined`

Is there anyway to get transform transitions to work in jsdom? Or is there an alternative that will work in node.js?

**UPDATE** - Here is a copy of my current files that I am running on node.js http://jsfiddle.net/1y9jhvtL/2/

Comment: I have uploaded my code to jsfiddle, but you will have to run it locally in node.js

Answer (score 1):

jsdom doesn't support the SVG DOM (... yet), so this can't work.

You may have luck with phantom.js, however it's not node but a headless webkit basically.
Maybe you could disable transitions in jsdom, but enable them on the client side?

Comment: well jsdom is working fine for svg when I disable transitions. jsdom just hasn't implemented SVGAnimatedTransformList. I am trying to use phantomjs-node but the evaluate function is completely sandboxed so I can't figure out how to get the data from the database and access it during that function